# How is possible this Gaussian Blur javascript algorithm work?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I found the following script to do a blur image processing to an image since javascript. I replicated the sample but I didn't understand how a little part of this script could work fine, I will show the script:

```
var gaussianBlur = function() {
  var data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  var px = data.data;
  var tmpPx = new Uint8ClampedArray(px.length);
  tmpPx.set(px);

  for (var i = 0, len= px.length; i < len; i++) {
     if (i % 4 === 3) {continue;}

     px[i] = ( tmpPx[i] 
        + (tmpPx[i - 4] || tmpPx[i])
        + (tmpPx[i + 4] || tmpPx[i]) 
        + (tmpPx[i - 4 * data.width] || tmpPx[i])
        + (tmpPx[i + 4 * data.width] || tmpPx[i]) 
        + (tmpPx[i - 4 * data.width - 4] || tmpPx[i])
        + (tmpPx[i + 4 * data.width + 4] || tmpPx[i])
        + (tmpPx[i + 4 * data.width - 4] || tmpPx[i])
        + (tmpPx[i - 4 * data.width + 4] || tmpPx[i])
        )/9;
  };
  // data.data = px;

  ctx.putImageData(data,0,0);
  delete tmpPx;
  btnBlur.removeAttribute('disabled');
  btnBlur.textContent = 'Blur'; }
```

This function (`gaussianBlur()`) is triggered to a html button, so when it's clicked, it will process the image to get it blurred and this process will be repeated according to the number of clicks on the button. The part of the code I don't understand is when it finishes the for loop, all the math operations were saved on the `px` variable but in the next line code `ctx.putImageData(data,0,0);`, this `data` variable doesn't take the new changed variable `px`. So I wonder, how is it possible that the canvas could render with the image blurred if `data` variable wasn't changed its `data` component (because `data.data = px` as shown in the first lines of `gaussianBlur` function).

In my opinion, to understand this code, I would put a  `data.data = px;` after the for loop, with this line code I am saying that the new `px` will be set on `data.data` variable. And with ot without this line code the algorithm works. So I am confused why it works despite `data.data` is not set by the new `px` value. Please help me to understand it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `px` *references* the same underlying `Uint8ClampedArray` that `data.data` references. All non [primitive types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive) in javascript are references.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is actually a Gaussian blur and not just a box blur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening, is that `px` is in reality the same object as `data.data`, meaning that every changes in `px` take effect in the object you would think is just a copy.
Look at this simple example:

```
// We create an object 'x' with an array of data
var x = {
    data :[ 0, 1]
};

// Assign x.data value to 'p'
var p = x.data;
console.log(p); // [0, 1]
// Then we change one of the array's values to 'Xpto'
p[1] = "Xpto";
// Now look what happened to x.data
console.log(x.data); // [0, "Xpto"]
```

This is why your code isn't working. `px` is not a copy, it is a reference.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand it, in which pages i can see that documentation? (about the references on js and how it works)